# Weird PHP Startup Error

Tags: php

Since switching hosting providers about a week ago, I've been getting this error showing up in my php error log about twice per day:

> PHP Fatal error:  PHP Startup: UID: 506: apc_fcntl_create: failed to determine username: getpwuid(geteuid()) failed: Success. in Unknown on line 0

So far as I can tell my site is working perfectly fine, but it's unnerving to have this error and I do not know what it is.

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: apc is advanced PHP cache, an opcode cache for PHP.... it can boost performance, because your PHP code is compiled only once on the very first request, but PHP will simply recompile on every request without it

Comment: It is only critical if it is also being used to store userdata, without checking if it's actually enabled

Comment: With modern versions of PHP, you shouldn't be using APC for opcode caching anyway, because there's the built-in opcache instead